# bindkey to Alt + Shift + p has no effect

Tags: zsh, terminal.app, iterm2

Capital <kbd>p</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> no longer seem to register as keystroes on my Mac OS with iTerm 2 (or Terminal). Therefore this key has no effect:

```
bindkey -s "^[P" "echo 'I cannot trigger this'"
```

If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, nothing appears on screen.

#### Additional clues

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> works fine. It seems there's some corner case with P that is failing
- WITHOUT shift, everything works as expected.

```
bindkey -s "^[p" "echo 'I can trigger this'"
```

I recall that some keystrokes have unexpected meanings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> trigger the same escape sequence) but beyond that I'm confused. How can I assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to a key binding?

#### EDIT

If I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> it works. I thought that means this is an iTerm issue, but even Terminal.app has the same behaviour. It works with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but not with <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I don't use MacOS, but might it be the case that you (or some update) defined a global shortcut `Alt+Shift+P` so that combination isn't sent anymore to the terminal?

Comment: Hmm I use karabiner which is capable of doing that. Come to think of it, I should test this out on Ubuntu or a docker image.